# Querying to display the correct values for reporting using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This site is very good source as reference in my learning basically in SQL, but now I have difficulty in retrieving the values that I want to display for reporting

I have 4 tables LEFT JOIN together

**itm_invoice**

```
 | invoiceNo | invoiceDate | invoiceTime | clientNo  
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+---------
 |    00001  |  2017-11-16 |   14:24:50  | CA001
```

**itm_invoice_det**

```
 | invoiceNo | itemIndex |  price | qty   
 +-----------+-----------+--------+-----
 |    00001  |  it001    |   1.0  |  2  
 |    00001  |  it002    |  10.0  |  5  
 |    00001  |  it003    |   3.0  |  5
```

**itm_invoice_pay**

```
 | invoiceNo | payTypeNo | receiptTotal | amount | memo  
 +-----------+-----------+--------------+--------+-----
 |    00001  |        1  |       2      |    2   | NPI   
 |    00001  |        2  |      50      |   50   |  
 |    00001  |        3  |      15      |   15   | SSD
```

**ref_invoice_pay**

```
 | payTypeNo | payTypeName   
 +-----------+------------
 |    1      | cash       
 |    2      | cheque     
 |    3      | bank
```

and this is my query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(itm_invoice.invoiceDate, '%m/%d/%Y') AS 'DATE_',
itm_invoice.invoiceNo AS 'INVOICE_#',
itm_invoice.clientNo AS 'CLIENT_', 
man_item.itemName AS 'ITEM_',   
itm_invoice_det.qty AS 'QTY_', 
itm_invoice_det.price AS 'AMOUNT_', 
itm_invoice_pay.receiptTotal AS 'TOTAL_',
ref_invoice_pay.paymentTypeName AS 'TENDER_', 
itm_invoice_pay.amount AS 'AMOUNT_', 
itm_invoice_pay.memo AS 'MEMO_', 
man_user.username AS 'CASHIER_', 
ref_invoice_status.statusName AS 'STATUS_' 
FROM itm_invoice 
LEFT JOIN itm_invoice_det ON itm_invoice_det.invoiceNo = 
itm_invoice.invoiceNo 
LEFT JOIN itm_invoice_pay ON itm_invoice_pay.invoiceNo = 
itm_invoice.invoiceNo 
LEFT JOIN ref_invoice_pay ON ref_invoice_pay.paymentTypeNo = 
itm_invoice_pay.paymentTypeNo 
LEFT JOIN man_item ON man_item.itemNo = itm_invoice_det.itemIndex
LEFT JOIN man_client ON man_client.clientNo = itm_invoice.clientNo 
LEFT JOIN man_user ON man_user.EmpCode = itm_invoice.encodeBy 
LEFT JOIN ref_invoice_status ON 
ref_invoice_status.statusNo=itm_invoice.status 
WHERE (itm_invoice.invoiceDate >= '2017-11-16' AND itm_invoice.invoiceDate 
<= '2017-11-16') AND (itm_invoice.invoiceTime >= '00:00:00' AND 
itm_invoice.invoiceTime <= '23:59:59') AND 
(ref_invoice_status.statusName='Active' OR 
ref_invoice_status.statusName='Pending') 
GROUP BY itm_invoice_det.itemIndex ASC
```

[This is the query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt5WF.png)

and now i have my dilemma in to display the correct values in my report viewer. as you can see, the TENDER and AMOUNT column have the same values but it has different value in table itm_invoice_pay.

I hope you can help me with this query. Thank you and I am very sorry for posting image of the output. I am using only my mobile.

Thank you

PS: i am not using any stored procedure. its plainly sql syntax

Comment: I doubt if a group by is what you want - have another read of the manual.

Comment: Would you like to add the man_ and ref_invoice_status table details or take them out of the query in the question? Better if you have all the tables defined in the query represented in your question.

Comment: And fix the name differences between table column names and query table column names.

Comment: That query is just too complex to be trying to pick a problem with. In such cases, start from scratch with as simple a query as possible and build it up bit by bit, adding a new bit only when you have confirmed that the previous bit works as intended. That means adding one table at a time and omitting any nonessential columns.

Comment: i will try to reconstruct my table structure. thanks guys